# How to add dynamic range to database (store the ranges in a table)

Tags: mysql, database

```
Table  (CostTitle)
Id_            _costTitle_      
1                   A          
2                   B           
3                   C         
4                   D         
5                   E           
6                   F
```

- A Refers numbers between 0-99
- B Refers numbers between 100-199
- C Refers numbers between 200-299
- D Refers numbers between 300-399
- E Refers numbers between 400-499
- F Refers numbers between 500-599

costCode  will be base on costTitle's refers numbers

```
Table  (CostCode)
Id_            _costTitle_        _costCode_    _costProductTitle_
1                   A                12             productX
2                   B                111            productY
3                   B                142            productZ
4                   C                201            productK
5                   F                511            productL
6                   F                582            productM
```

I am trying to add product and assign dynamically cost code.

Thanks for advance

Comment: If your looking for SQL code try checking this out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to store the ranges in a table. So you need a BEFORE INSERT trigger, which sets new.costTitle. Triggers are explained here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html

MariaDB offers an alternative: dynamic columns. However, because of the limits of this feature, you cannot store the ranges in a different table. You will need to hardcode the ranges in the virtual column definition, which doesn't seem to me a great idea (but you decide, of course).

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.As you understand i am trying to store the ranges in a table. But some hosting companies doesn't support "BEFORE INSERT trigger" ( like Godaddy ).

Comment: Host companies don't allow the use of triggers and stored procedures at all. I'm afraid that you will need to set that value via your application, or use another solution for your website.